# Get the coordinates of seaborn barplot with nested grouping

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a barplot with nested grouping using `seaborn` and the `hue` keyword argument. I want to draw statistical annotations on this plot. For this I need the x- and y-coordinates for **each** bar. How can I do that?

This is my plot:

[image]

Comment: Similar logic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579284/matplotlib-get-coordinates-of-top-and-bottom-of-horizontal-bar-edges)

Comment: `ax.patches()` returns the coordinates.

Comment: Providing a figure and expecting an answer is too broad for Stack Overflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).